# How to stop mouseenter animation after delay of 1000ms( If mouse is not on that element anymore )

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Following is the code for a box, which has sliding options(.box-options) animating out of the box on mouseenter with added delay of 1000ms

i want to stop the animation(or sliding it's options out) if mouse is out of that box before completing 1000ms

I don't want to use any external plugin, Only JQuery I have.

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).find('.box-options').stop().delay(1000).animate({
            right: "-42"
        },400);
    });
```

Comment: The idea is to add a callback that will be called after 1000ms (using for instance, the setTimeout() function of pure javascript) of the mouseenter event, check if the mouse is still in the box and if not, cancel the animation of the box options. Depending on your setup, cancelling the animation may mean hiding the box options, putting them back in the original position or even freezing them halfway.

Comment: @CarolineAlexiou I already tried setTimeout. I couldn't figure out how to do that.
. Can you please help me with the code above

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LA7Kc/ (edited Lawrence Jones fiddle)

Comment: I was unaware that you had to fork a fiddle to save the changes. Here's what my fiddle was meant to look like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne8fN/), but at least now you've got a javascript and css solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, assuming you want to freeze the animation in its tracks if the mouse stops hovering over the box.

```
var animInProgress = false;

$('.box').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).find('.box-options').animate({
        right: "-42"
    },400);
        animInProgress = true;
        setTimeout(stop_animation,1000);
});

$('.box').on('mouseleave', function(){
    // if the mouse leaves the box before the animation is finished
    if(animInProgress) {

        // stop the animation
         $(this).find('.box-options').stop()
        // or do something else (revert to original pos?)

}

});

function stop_animation() {    
    animInProgress = false;
}
```

Comment: i forked your fiddle into [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/zorbash/LA7Kc/1/) have a look

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of CSS animations. Not only do they require less work to get up and running, but browsers are optimised like crazy for CSS and perform far more efficiently than an equivalent Javascript tween effect.

For something like this, I would recommend having the on mouseenter event apply a class to the box-option elements that triggers a CSS animation.

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).find('.box-options').addClass('active');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).find('.box-options').removeClass('active');
});
```

Of course if you were clever about it, you could use the CSS psuedo selector `:hover` in combination with `-webkit-transition` to achieve this all without javascript. See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne8fN/) which uses absolutely no Javascript. This is definitely the superior way of managing this effect.